# how to make react based extension that gets complied with rollup to also compile icons folder and popup pages

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, rollup

I'm new to React-based Chrome extensions and extensions in general. I have created an extension for saving notes. Here is the GitHub link to it:

https://github.com/HexaCode-web/Note-Keeper

And here is the Rollup config file:

```
import path from 'path'
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

import { chromeExtension } from 'rollup-plugin-chrome-extension'
import { emptyDir } from 'rollup-plugin-empty-dir'
import zip from 'rollup-plugin-zip'
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

export default {
  input: 'src/manifest.json',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
    chunkFileNames: path.join('chunks', '[name]-[hash].js'),
  },
  plugins: [
    chromeExtension(),
    // Adds a Chrome extension reloader during watch mode

    // Replace environment variables
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    babel({
      // Do not transpile dependencies
      ignore: ['node_modules'],
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    // Empties the output dir before a new build
    emptyDir(),
    postcss({ plugins: [] }),
    // Outputs a zip file in ./releases
    isProduction && zip({ dir: 'releases' }),
  ],
}
```

thats the manifst file :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "NoteKeeper",
  "version": "2.2.5",
  "description": "Notes",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background/index.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "pages/popup/index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "128": "icons/icon.png"
    }
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

now I have icons folder inside the src but the rollup doesn't see it
also, I want to make popup pages, but they don't get complied, thanks in advance!